# Is there a way to remove all local changesets to save space?

Tags: mercurial

In other words, is there a way to revert an hg repository back to the state that existed when you first performed an hg clone against a foreign repository, and before you did a pull?

I am trying to save space when FTPing a server VM and the hg repositories exist elsewhere so there is no reason to transfer them.  I would like to set the server up in such a way that all that has to be done on the other end is hg pull, hg update and it's ready to go again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to strip your clone to the bare minimum and still recover from the original repository.  Why not just delete the local copies completely and just keep a list of the clone paths to get them back again?

Otherwise (and assuming you've pushed anything you want to keep) using the `strip` command from the MercurialQueues extension you can eliminate all local history of a clone with `hg strip 0 --no-backup` and bring it all back with `hg pull`.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in a single mercurial command. Once you've run `hg pull`, mercurial doesn't keep a record of what the state was before that pull.

But, if you keep a record of what the changeset was when you cloned (e.g. just by writing it to some untracked file), you can quite efficiently strip out all the changesets you don't want. See [Mercurial: removing changesets](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EditingHistory#Basic_changeset_removal_with_clone)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't committed or run any other commands that changed the internal state of the repository since the last pull, you can run [hg rollback](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#rollback).